# jquery datepicker not hiding on ios when clicked on background

Tags: ios, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a small problem with the jquery datepicker and ios.

When clicked on the input field the datepicker appears as expected.
But when clicked on the background (without selecting a date) the datepicker should hide. This works on desktop but not on all the ios divices I tested.
An example setup can be found on this [pen](http://codepen.io/Ixillion/pen/NPjPKJ)

```
<div id="test">
    <form class="booking-form" action="#" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="check_in_date" name="check_in_date" placeholder="Check-in-date">
        <input type="text" id="check_out_date" name="check_out_date" placeholder="Check-out-date">
        <input class="bookbutton" name="booking_step_1_submit" type="submit" value="Check Availability" />
</form>
</div>

    $("#check_in_date").attr('readonly', true);
        $("#check_out_date").attr('readonly', true);

        var array_1 = ["2015-01-24","2015-01-26","2015-01-27", "2015-01-28"];

        $( "#check_in_date" ).datepicker({
              minDate: 0,
              maxDate: "+1y",
              changeMonth: true,
              numberOfMonths: 1,
              dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
              beforeShowDay: function(date){
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                return [ array_1.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
              },
              onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                  if (selectedDate) {
                    $( "#check_out_date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );

                  }
              }

            });
        $( "#check_out_date" ).datepicker({
              minDate: 0,
              maxDate: "+1y",
              changeMonth: true,
              numberOfMonths: 1,
              dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
              beforeShowDay: function(date){
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                return [ array_1.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
              },
              onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                  if (selectedDate) {
                $( "#check_in_date ").datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate);

                  }
              }

            });
```

I would like to know if there is a work around for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this response is a bit late, but I just ran across this same issue when testing on my iPhone.  I think this may be a longstanding jquery ui bug.

See this ticket detailing the issue:
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9308

And this page detailing the root cause and possible workarounds:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click#Safari_Mobile

> Safari Mobile 7.0+ (and likely earlier versions too) suffers from a
> bug where click events aren't fired on elements that aren't typically
> interactive (e.g. ) and which also don't have event listeners
> directly attached to the elements themselves (i.e. event delegation is
> being used). See this live example for a demonstration. See also
> Safari's docs on making elements clickable and the definition of
> "clickable element".
>
> Known workarounds for this bug:
>
> - Set `cursor: pointer;` on the element or any of its ancestors.
> - Add a dummy `onclick=""` attribute to the element or any of its ancestors up to but not including `<body>`.
> - Use a typically interactive element (e.g. `<a>`) instead instead of one that isn't typically interactive (e.g. `<div>`).
> - Stop using click event delegation.

Comment: This is useful information, but would be more helpful if you quoted the linked sites in-line in your answer to concisely explain the workarounds.