# jQuery UI datepicker doesn't close on the iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

The datepicker usually works on the PC, but not in iPad's browser. In `beforeShow`, I add the button to close:

```
var headerPane = $("#ui-datepicker-div");
headerPane.append("<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='close-datepicker'>");
```

Close:

```
closeDatePicker: function(){
    $.datepicker._hideDatepicker();
} ...
```

In events have the click:

```
Events: function(){
  $('body').on('click', '.close-datepicker' this.closeDatePicker)
}
```

I've tried with `.datepicker("hide")` and also nothing.

Comment: Can't Close means the Calender Popup still there even after clicking close? Which Browser?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just simple syntax issue somewhere...

Your `headerPane.append(...)` opens a HTML A tag; do you close it properly somewhere?

In your events function, are you missing a comma after `'.close-datepicker'`?

Comment: It is not, because when I click a date in the datepicker closes, only the close button nothing happens. Remembering that this occurs only on the iPad

Comment: Any possibility of you sharing relevant portions of the code so I can play with it?

Answer (score 0):

I think [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006056/jquery-datepicker-not-hiding-on-ios-when-clicked-on-background) applies to this question too.  Basically I just added `OnClick=""` to the parent div containing my datepicker input.  That was the simplest fix for my iOS Datepicker not closing problem and I didn't need any special close handler logic as a workaround like you seem to be attempting.  It still doesn't close when I select "done" from the iOS date selector, but it does close when I click elsewhere on the page.